# Django makemigrations make change for 'auth.user' every time

Tags: django, model, migration, django-south

I upgrade my system's django version from 1.6.10 to 1.8.16 for test.
On before version, i use South for migration.
So, I followed 'https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south' this documentation.

My problem is every makemigrations are check same field, then make migration file.
That field is 'auth.User' foreign key field. like `user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')`.

here are my screenshot for that problem.

[image]

[image]

This is Sample code for that foreign key field.

```
cancelled_by = models.ForeignKey(
    'auth.User',
    verbose_name=_("Cancelled by"),
    related_name='project_cancel',
    blank=True,
    null=True
)
```

How can i fix it?

edited:
This is my migration file created by makemigrations after all migration.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('meeting', '0003_meeting_proposal'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='meeting',
        name='manager',
        field=models.ForeignKey(verbose_name='Manager', blank=True, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True),
    ),
]
```

Comment: Have you run "migrate" after each makemigration?

Comment: @morinx yes. just migrate. should i fake?

Comment: I would first delete the recently made migration files and try makemigration again

Comment: @morinx okay, i will try and add the result to question.

Comment: also provide the result of "sqlmigrate" command for each migration file

Comment: only the ForeignKey to `User` getting  generated everytime?

Comment: @itzmeontv yes. It generate migrate only User.

Comment: @morinx I deleted all migrations file created after problem started. then, makemigrations one more time, and migrate. 

now problem has solved but i feel unrest about that for update to product. delete migration file and new migrate is only solution?

Comment: deleting migration files is a common solution since Django is smart enough to recreate them easily regardless of what has been changed in your folder

Comment: you can fake these migrations too, but i prefer to keep my migration folder clean and tidy

Comment: @morinx okay. thanks for your comment. if you want, create answer, to select yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first delete the recently made migration files and try makemigration again.

deleting migration files is a common solution since Django is smart enough to recreate them easily regardless of what has been changed in your folder.

you can fake these migrations too, but i prefer to keep my migration folder clean and tidy.